# Validate correct format for coordinate using REGEX

Tags: java, regex, latitude-longitude, coordinate

i've been trying to validate the correct format for coordinate. Currently i want to save the coordinate. But when the format is wrong, the markers wont appear on my map.

This is the some of my sample code.

```
String latlon = "3.169054, 101.714108";
        String regex_coords = "/\\((\\-?\\d+\\.\\d+), (\\-?\\d+\\.\\d+)\\)/";
        Pattern compiledPattern2 = Pattern.compile(regex_coords, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher2 = compiledPattern2.matcher(latlon);
        while (matcher2.find()) {
            System.out.println("Is Valid Map Coordinate: " + matcher2.group());
        }
```

I want the user to be able to save this format only "3.169054, 101.714108" with the comma.

Can anyone help me build the regex to valid this format?

Thanks all

Comment: Will the number of decimals always be 6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
([+-]?\d+\.?\d+)\s*,\s*([+-]?\d+\.?\d+)
```

Online RegexPlanet Demo: http://fiddle.re/20pm

This permits any coordinate to be a number which optionally starts with `+` or `-`. Number can be either integer or double (but dot must be enclosed with digits if present).

Finally, you can get latitude and longitude as group1 and group2.

Comment: This one is buggy and doesn't check the range -90 to 90 and -180 to 180.

Comment: @Sategroup: regexes are not right tool to check number ranges. This is only useful to extract coordinates from text for further processing and perhaps validation, but it's not and cannot be 100% correctness validation tool.

Comment: @mvp, as you correctly mentioned that Regex is for validation & question itself states `Validate correct format using regex`, your regex expression fails to perform that validation correctly. If you can correct your regex, I would be happy to up-vote it